# Read bulk records from dynamodb using json array of primary keys

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a json array of objects having primary key for single dynamodb table. Is there a way I can request record for all the keys using at once  java APIs or do I have to do it one by one?
Array is :

```
[
{ "id" : " 123"},
{ "id" : "11"}
]
```

I read about batchgetitem but was not able to understand its functionality and how to use it through java.
Can I read all the records. The code I have is able to get one row at a time but I think there must be a better way. Any sample code would be very helpful as I am very new to AWS APIs

Comment: Is it a hash table or hash and range?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of primary keys, the easiest way is to execute multiple GetItem requests (possibly in parallel to improve performance) to get the items one by one. [Example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIItemCRUD.html#JavaDocumentAPIGetItem) of GetItem in Java.

You can also use BatchGetItem but your accesses will probably be less uniform over time (E.g. you may have bursts of requesting 25 items + possible retrying anything that was throttled). [Example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/batch-operation-document-api-java.html#JavaDocumentAPIBatchGet) of BatchGetItem in Java if you are ok with making the performance tradeoff for code simplicity.

Both approaches will have the same costs (throughput consumed) but parallel individual requests gives you more flexibility in how they are done which can improve performance.